# Trying to redeem my Fallout 3 code but getting a Xbos-0x80153016 error

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, fallout-3

When I go to the http://xbox.com/redeemcode page and try to redeem the Fallout 3 code that came with my copy of Fallout 4 I just get an error code.

```
Xbos-0x80153016
```

Unfortunately there is no accompanying message explaining what this code means.

Comment: Googling the error a month ago brought me to a wide variety of answers. Some right, some wrong. Some with very bad advice. Posting the question and answer here is an attempt to get more visibility to the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the region of the Xbox website had defaulted back to "English (United States)". Once I changed it to my own region "English (United Kingdom)", I was able to redeem the code without issue.